# La longitud de la cadena supera el valor establecido en la propiedad maxJsonLenght

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc

estoy enviando a través de Ajax una imagen en Base64, esto por que estoy usando un PlugIn de Apache Cordova para tomar fotos. El resultado en Base64 lo envío al servidor de MVC en un JsonResult. El problema es que cuando la cadena es muy larga el servidor me retorna el error del titulo, ya he intentado cambiar el webconfig para que el JavaScriptSerializer acepte más datos pero sin resultados.

Cabe destacar que estoy **recibiendo** datos, no enviando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi código de HTML .

```
 function subir(imageData) {

        var x = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData;
        //imageData es la Base64 de la imagen
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: uri,
            data: JSON.stringify({ base64image: x }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Y mi código de MVC

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GuardarImagenBase64(string base64image)  
    {


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64image))
            return Json(0);

        var t = base64image.Substring(22);  // remove data:image/png;base64,

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t);

        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        var randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".png";
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/"), randomFileName);
        image.Save(fullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        return Json(1);
    }
```

En mi Web.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación ASP.NET, visite
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"  maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    //Omití esto pero si tengo mi conexión
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1073741824"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

¿Qué tengo que hacer para poder hacer que acepte datos grandes? Imágenes pequeñas no hay problema, pero debido a que es una aplicación móvil y por lo regular las fotos de la cámara son de mucho peso siempre ocurre esto.

Comment: Hola, cual es tu configuración en el web.config?

Comment: Has evaluado en usar BSON en vez de JSON? Es mucho mas eficiente ya que no envía los contenidos en Base64. Mira este ejemplo [Compatibilidad con BSON en ASP.NET Web API 2.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21)

Comment: Hola. Qué tamaño tienen la imágenes? Puede verificar l cabecera Content-Length de la petición HTTP?

Comment: Has probado a usar el valor maximo de un entero (2147483647) en maxJsonLength?

Comment: He probado el valor maximo, la imagen que subo es de 2 Mb y el content lenght es de 3264160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ya lo pude resolver. Para esto tuve que crear una clase modificada que viene por defecto en Visual Studio que es la clase de JsonValueProviderFactory.

Dentro de App_Start cree una nueva clase que la llame CustomJsonValueProviderFactory y copie y pegue esto:

```
public sealed class CustomJsonValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{

    private static void AddToBackingStore(Dictionary<string, object> backingStore, string prefix, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> d = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (d != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in d)
            {
                AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakePropertyKey(prefix, entry.Key), entry.Value);
            }
            return;
        }

        IList l = value as IList;
        if (l != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
            {
                AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakeArrayKey(prefix, i), l[i]);
            }
            return;
        }

        // primitive
        backingStore[prefix] = value;
    }

    private static object GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // not JSON request
            return null;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
        string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
        {
            // no JSON data
            return null;
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; //increase MaxJsonLength.  This could be read in from the web.config if you prefer
        object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
        return jsonData;
    }

    public override System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        object jsonData = GetDeserializedObject(controllerContext);
        if (jsonData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Dictionary<string, object> backingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AddToBackingStore(backingStore, String.Empty, jsonData);
        return new System.Web.Mvc.DictionaryValueProvider<object>(backingStore, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    private static string MakeArrayKey(string prefix, int index)
    {
        return prefix + "[" + index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "]";
    }

    private static string MakePropertyKey(string prefix, string propertyName)
    {
        return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix)) ? propertyName : prefix + "." + propertyName;
    }
}
```

Esta clase lo que hace es quitarle el limite de JSON y lo pone a `int32.MaxValue`

Se requiere de estos Using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Por ultimo en el Global.asax dentro de las llaves de Application_Start()

```
JsonValueProviderFactory jsonValueProviderFactory = null;

        foreach (var factory in ValueProviderFactories.Factories)
        {
            if (factory is JsonValueProviderFactory)
            {
                jsonValueProviderFactory = factory as JsonValueProviderFactory;
            }
        }

        //remove the default JsonVAlueProviderFactory
        if (jsonValueProviderFactory != null) ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(jsonValueProviderFactory);

        //add the custom one
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new CustomJsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Va a ser necesario que en el Global.asax usen un `Using NombreDeProyecto.App_Start` con la referencia a su propio proyecto, sino entienden como es lo que digo, usen las Acciones rápidas y refactorizaciones.

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió mucho esta propuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muy útil, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

En tu `Web.Config` agrega la siguiente configuración:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1073741824"/>
        <!-- Esto representa 1Gb -->
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Lectura recomendada: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183.aspx

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, creo que con esa configuración no se solucionaria el problema. Ese parámetro indica el maximo numero de elementos que se pueden deserializar. OP hace referencia al tamaño del Json, no del numero de elementos.

Comment: copiado, actualizando respuesta :)

Comment: PD: esta es la primera vez en 2 años y medio (quizás un poquito más) donde le ponen un negativo a alguna respuesta que he dado. Las siguientes preguntas leeré con mayor detenimiento  para evitar confusiones :D

Comment: Ya lo agregue y no funciono

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu web.config por favor?

Comment: En este momento no puedo, no tengo mi PC a la mano, cuando pueda lo pondre en un Edit

Comment: Ya he añadaido el Web.config

Answer (score 1):

Esto me funciono

```
    public JsonResult ObtenerAsignaciones(string pStrIdTienda = null, int pIntStock = 2)
    {
        List<ProductoTienda> lista = CD_ProductoTienda.Instancia.ObtenerProductoTienda(((Usuario)Session["Usuario"]).IdATV, pStrIdTienda, null, pIntStock);
      
        var json = Json(new { data = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        json.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
        return json; 
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que estés superando con creces el limite que IIS tiene marcado por defecto para el tamaño de las peticiones.
Modifica tu web.config agregando lo siguiente

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
         <standardEndpoints>           
        <webHttpEndpoint>
     <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" /> 
        </webHttpEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=”524288000″/>
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

El tamaño indicado maxAllowedContentLength  es en bytes.

Comment: PD: Combina esta configuración con lo indicado en la respuesta de @fredyfx

Comment: No ha funcionado

Comment: Hola puedes poner en tu pregunta la configuración de tu web.config?

Comment: Ya lo he agregado

Comment: Hola, el mensaje de error es el mismo? Voy a editar mi respuesta para agregar mas configuraciones a tu web.config

Comment: Va dentro de las etiquetas configuration?

Comment: El error aún persiste